# Finding cones of directions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, constraints

[image]

a. We have that feasible directions is given by $D=\{d\neq 0:\overline x+\lambda d\in S,\lambda\in(0,\delta)\ for\ some\ delta>0\}$.

Thus I have to find $\delta>0$ such that  $(\lambda d_1\ \lambda d_2)^t\in S$.

But I don't know how to do it. I already draw $S$ (it's an infinite positive rectangle with missing right corner side)

A direction $d$ is an attainable directions if $\exists\delta>0$ and $\alpha:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_n$ such that $\alpha(\lambda)\in S$ and $\alpha(0)=\overline x$ and $d=\lim_{\lambda\to0^+}\frac{\alpha(\lambda)-\alpha(0)}{\lambda}$.

Here again I don't know how to find the delta and the alpha function,

Please someone help me how to construct both of them?

Thanks in advance for your patience :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, it is easier to understand the definitions if you look at the geometry of the sets $S$. I'll look at parts a. and c. here.

Before we start, I think you're missing something small from the definition of attainable directions. I think it should read:

> A direction $d$ is attainable at $\overline{x}$ if there exists $\delta>0$ and $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\alpha(\lambda)\in{S}$ for all $\lambda\in(0,\delta)$, $\alpha(0)=\overline{x}$, and $$\lim_{\lambda\to0^+}\frac{\alpha(\lambda)-\alpha(0)}{\lambda}=d.$$

**Part a.**
Our set $S$ looks like this: [image: feasible region for part a]

where the shaded region is the set $S$. The hatched region is both the cone of feasible directions and the cone of attainable directions at the point $(0,0)$ (they are the same in this example).

**Cone of Feasible Directions**

The cone of feasible directions at $(0,0)$ (which we denote $D_0$) are essentially the points that can be connected to the origin with a straight line, while staying in the set $S$. For example, the point $(0,1)$ is in $D_0$ because it's a non-zero vector, and 
$$ (0,0)+\lambda(0,1)=(0,\lambda)\in S\text{ for all }\lambda\geqslant0. $$
So in this case, we could take $\delta$ to be any positive real number. Let's look at a point where we can't do that.

Consider the vector $(-2,-2)$. We want to show that this point is in $D_0$, so we need to find the $\delta>0$ that satisfies the definition. We want that
$$ (0,0)+\lambda(-2,-2)=(-2\lambda,-2\lambda)\in{S} $$
for all $\lambda\in(0,\delta)$.
Looking at the picture, the farthest we can go is to the point $(-1,-1)\in{S}$. Hence, we must take $\delta\leqslant1/2$ ($\delta=1/2$ will do just fine).

Now let's look at a counter-example: why is the point $(1,1)$ *not* in $D_0$? If it were, we should be able to find a $\delta>0$ which satisfies the definition, so that
$$ (0,0)+\lambda(1,1)=(\lambda,\lambda)\in{S} $$
for all $\lambda\in(0,\delta)$. Looking at the picture, it is clear that no such $\delta$ exists. As a proof: suppose such a $\delta>0$ exists. Take $\lambda=\min\{\delta,1/2\}$. Then the point
$$ (0,0)+\lambda(1,1)=(\lambda,\lambda)\not\in{S}, $$
a contradiction.

To write it out formally, we have
$$ D_0=\{d\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ d_1\leqslant{d_2}\text{ and }d_1\leqslant0\}$$

**Cone of Attainable Directions**

In this example, these cones are the same. I'm going to skip ahead to part c., where they are different, so that the  difference is clearer.

**Part c.**
Now our feasible set $S$ looks like this (I have marked the origin with a black dot for clarity).

[image: feasible region for part c]

**Cone of Feasible Directions**

Recall that intuitively, the cone of feasible directions are the points that we can connect to the origin with a straight line, while staying in the set $S$. Since the set $S$ in this case isn't a straight line, you might expect that $D_0$ is empty. Indeed, it is empty. To prove this, suppose not, *i.e.* suppose there exists $(d_1,d_2)\in{D_0}$, with associated $\delta>0$. Then for all $\lambda\in(0,\delta)$, we must have
$$ (0,0)+\lambda(d_1,d_2)=(\lambda d_1,\lambda d_2)\in{S}, $$
which means that
$$ \lambda d_2=-\lambda^3 d_1^3 $$
for all $\lambda\in(0,\delta)$. Since $\lambda>0$ we can divide by it:
$$ d_2=-\lambda^2 d_1^3. $$
Since this holds for all $\lambda\in(0,\delta)$, we must have that $d_1=0$. (To see this, suppose $d_1\neq0$. Then we can divide by it to get $(-d_2/d_1^3)=-\lambda^2$. The left hand side is a constant, while the right hand side is an arbitrary scalar in $(0,\delta)$, a contradiction.) So $d_1=0$ thus $d_2=0$. This is contradiction ($d$ must be non-zero if $d\in{D_0}$). Hence $D_0=\varnothing$.

**Cone of Attainable Directions**

Even though the cone of feasible directions $D_0$ is empty, when we look at the picture above, it looks as though we should be able to move from side to side a little bit, and remain feasible. This is the idea that the cone of attainable directions (which we notate $A_0$) captures.

So we guess that $(1,0)\in{A_0}$. How do we prove it? We need the function $\alpha$. All that $\alpha$ is is a path in $S$ that goes to the point $(0,0)$. This path $\alpha$ doesn't have to be straight (note: the cone of feasible directions is just the cone of attainable directions with the extra restriction that the paths $\alpha$ have to be straight lines).

Looking at $S$ above, it's pretty clear that the only way that the path $\alpha$ can stay in $S$ is if it follows along the function $y=-x^3$ exactly. So let's define $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$ \alpha(\lambda)=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\-\lambda^3\end{pmatrix}. $$
It's clear that $\alpha(\lambda)\in{S}$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence, we can take any $\delta>0$. It's also clear that $\alpha(0)=(0,0)$, as desired. All the we need to show now is that
$$
\lim_{\lambda\to0^+}\frac{\alpha(\lambda)-\alpha(0)}{\lambda}=d(=(1,0),\text{ remember}).
$$
Good news:
$$
\lim_{\lambda\to0^+}\frac{\alpha(\lambda)-\alpha(0)}{\lambda}
=\lim_{\lambda\to0^+}\frac{\alpha(\lambda)}{\lambda}
=\lim_{\lambda\to0^+}\frac{1}{\lambda}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\-\lambda^3\end{pmatrix}
=\lim_{\lambda\to0^+}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-\lambda^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},
$$
as desired.

For practice, you can try a similar proof to show that $(-1,0)$ is also in $A_0$.

The final answer is
$$A_0=\{(\alpha,0)\ |\ \alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

Comment: I have a question, why $(-2,2)\in D_0$? I understand the analytic argument but in the region seems like the 'final' point is $(-1,1)$

Comment: I assume you mean $(-2,-2)$ and $(-1,-1)$? The point $(-2,-2)\in{D_0}$, but $(-2,-2)\not\in{S}$. In general, $D_0\not\subset{S}$. Remember that $D_0$ is the _cone_ of the feasible solutions--it extends to infinity. This is done for analytical reasons to make some proofs easier. I will update my figures to make this clearer.

Comment: yeah I meant $(-2,-2)$ and $(-1,-1)$

Comment: I see, I got confussed a bit.

Comment: See if the updated figure makes more sense.

Comment: yes, thank you again. Have to go,I hope to find you later because I have more doubts..

Comment: In part **c.**, for feasible directions, why do you know that $d_1=0$?

Comment: I've understand the idea of attainable and feasible directions with the particular examples, how the set $D_0$ and $A_0$should be written for the general case? I think it's $D_0=\{d\neq\in\mathbb R_2:\exists \delta>0,(\lambda d_1\ \lambda d_2)\in S,0<\lambda\le\delta\}$ That's what the exercise ask, no?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: $(-d_2/d_1^3)=-\lambda^2$ constant$\neq$arbitrary scalar, can they never be equal?, both are reals. Sounds a little bit weird, I've never seen an argument like that.

Comment: They can be equal _for one particular_ $\lambda$. But we require it to be true for all $\lambda\in(0,\delta)$. That’s the contradiction. There may be other ways to prove it, but this valid.

Comment: Got it, thanks :). If it's not much to ask, would you mind to take a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806898/cone-of-tangents-of-s-x-yy-ge-x3 ?